# Poor bandwidth after re-coupling an Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet

As part of an experiment I cut a Cat 5e Ethernet cable in half, stripped off a small amount of insulation on each wire and attached each pair of wires together with its own alligator clip.

There are four twisted pairs, so eight pairs of alligator clips are used.

Before cutting it in half I am able to transfer data between two computers using the cable and get ~940MBit/s which is close to the Gigabit/s speeds that Cat 5e is cable of.

However, after cutting it in half and reattaching the wires with alligator clips I get a 10x reduction in bandwidth and get a ~94MBits/s

What might be the reason for this and are there any techniques I can use to regain the original 940MBit/s speed.

Comment: By removing the twisting, you have created magnetic loops which pick up noise, e.g. the crosstalk data from the other pairs, easily. To fix this, use a cable you haven't damaged beyond repair.

Comment: Cat5e is specified to have certain characteristics (impedance, capacitance, inductance...), by cutting it and crudely rejoining these characteristics will have been modified. It's impressive it still manages nearly 100MBit!

Comment: Do wire wrap, don't use crocodile clip.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever heard of the requirement to maintain impedances on fast data lines? 940 Mbps can be regarded as a frequency of 470 MHz in that the equivalent symbol rate is 940 Mbps and at this frequency, one wavelength is about 0.64 metres (as an air borne radio wave). In cable this reduces because the velocity of propagation is something like 70% so the wavelength becomes smaller at about 0.45 metres.

As a golden rule, to avoid disrupting impedances too much and causing bad reflections, engineers use the rule that you should avoid uncontrolled runs of data that are more than one-tenth of the wavelength. One tenth of 0.45 metres is 45 mm.

So if you have splayed open the cable in order to attach crocodile clips and the overall length of that "modification" is greater than about 45 mm (including the croc clip length) then you are on the verge of asking for trouble.

Comment: I reduced the length of my crocodile clips significantly, although it was still longer than 45mm. It turns out the reason for this was a software issue! The almost exactly 10x drop in speed was due to the autonegotiation step within the Ethernet protocol. When I turned this off using ethtool I was surprisingly able to regain the full gigabit/s speed.

Comment: Hah! Well done but, I think you might still be on the verge of trouble. Take what I said on-board for next time!